# scp on specific files using regex (*)

Tags: bash, scp

Hello I have a disrectory in a server such as :

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
file2_JU.out
file4.out
file2_JU.out
file1_JU.out
file4_JU.out
file4.out
```

and I would like to scp only the file containing  a `_JU` so I tried ;

```
scp serve1@:/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file*_JU.out
 /mycomputeur/dir/
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I remember `scp` should send `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file*_JU.out` to the remote machine and you need backslashes to prevent the shell from interpreting it.

```
scp serve1@:/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file\*_JU.out /mycomput
```

You can also try:

```
scp "serve1@:/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/[*_JU.out]" /mycomput
```

Also:

```
scp 'serve1@:/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file*_JU.out' /mycomput
```

---

<sub>didn't test it</sub>